# Why does np.argwhere's result shape not match it's input?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I pass a 1D array:

```
>>> np.arange(0,20)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])
>>> np.arange(0,20).shape
(20,)
```

into argwhere:

```
>>> np.argwhere(np.arange(0,20)<10)
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
>>> np.argwhere(np.arange(0,20)<10).shape
(10, 1)
```

why has the result changed into a 2D array? What's the benefit of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`argwhere` returns the coordinates of where condition is True. In general, coordinates are tuples, therefore the output should be 2D.

```
>>> np.argwhere(np.arange(0,20).reshape(2,2,5)<10)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 4],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 4]])
```

For consistency, this also applies to the case of 1D input.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.argwhere` finds **indices** of elements that fulfill the condition. it happened that some of your elements are the outputted elements themselves (the index is the same as value).

Particularly, in your example the input is one dimensional, the output is one dimension (index) by two (the second is to iterate over values).

I hope this is clear, if not, take this example of two dimensional input array presented in the documentation of numpy:

```
>>> x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.argwhere(x>1)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`argwhere` is simply the transpose of `where` (actually `np.nonzero`):

```
In [17]: np.where(np.arange(0,20)<10)
Out[17]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),)
In [18]: np.transpose(_)
Out[18]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

`where` produces a tuple of arrays, one array per dimension (here a 1 element tuple). `transpose` turns that tuple into an array (e.g. `(1,10)` shape), and then transposes it.  So it's number of columns is the `ndim` of the input condition, and the number of rows the number of `finds`.

`argwhere` can be useful in visualizing the finds, but is not as useful in programs as the `where` itself.  The `where` tuple can be used to index the condition array directly.  The `argwhere` array is usually used iteratively.  For example:

```
In [19]: x = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
In [20]: x %2
Out[20]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
In [21]: np.where(x%2)
Out[21]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([1, 3, 0, 2, 4]))
In [22]: np.argwhere(x%2)
Out[22]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4]])
In [23]: x[np.where(x%2)]
Out[23]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
In [24]: for i in np.argwhere(x%2):
    ...:     print(x[tuple(i)])
    ...:     
1
3
5
7
9
In [25]: [x[tuple(i)] for i in np.argwhere(x%2)]
Out[25]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```